# Front USB Ports Dont Detect Anything

Tags: 14.04, usb

While reading and following [this](http://www.kdab.com/setting-up-kinect-for-programming-in-linux-part-1/) I realized after a while that my front USB ports weren’t detecting anything. The rear ports work fine, however.

**lsusb**

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 14cd:125c Super Top SD card reader
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**dmesg**

```
http://pastebin.com/YJcvJRZK
```

Yes, I know my drives made by the Ubuntu installer cause errors, but thats not the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to this where my front USB ports wouldn't detect anything except a mouse... It turned out I Needed to turn of USB legacy support in the BIOS.  Another thing to look at is that the cable is plugged into the motherboard, its easy to knock a cable loose inside your case.  Have these ports ever worked, like with other OS's or is this the first time you've ever tried to use them?

Hope this helps.

Comment: First I've Only Ever Had Ubuntu On This Computer, I'm Pretty Sure Following The Tutorial I Stated Messed Up My USB Ports. Also Legacy Support On My Motherboard Is Enabled.